# How to source all files in a directory?

Tags: bash

Why doesn't this work?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 .
```

All I get is `xargs: .: Permission denied`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you run `. file`, you invoke a the shell builtin `.` . Your `xargs` variant tries to execute the current directory.
Even if that did invoke the builtin, that command runs in a subshell, so all the "sourcing" would be useless.

Use shell globbing and a loop for that:

```
for file in * ; do
  if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    . "$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Clean solution; good to know that you cannot use builtins with `xargs` (and `find`'s `-exec` primary, for that matter). Here's the equivalent one-liner: `for f in *; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && . "$f";  done`

Comment: If you still want to use find: `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do echo "$f"; done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)`

Answer (score 1):

@Mat's solution is the cleanest, but *in case you're interested in some bash-fu for the fun of it*, the following solution, based on the original `find` command, works, too:

```
eval $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo . \'{}\'';' \;)
```

- `find` is used with `-exec` to construct a sourcing command for each file found, e.g. `. './foo';`. Note the escaped single quotes to ensure that filenames with special chars. are handled properly.
- `find` will return a newline-separated list of sourcing commands; by using command substitution (`$()`) *without* double-quoting, the shell folds these lines into a single line using a space each as the separator.
- Finally, `eval` executes the full list of sourcing commands in the context of the current shell (verified on OS X 10.8.1).

NOTE: One potential problem with this solution is that the command string can get large - possibly too large - with many files and/or long filenames present.